# Storing results in a @api variable returns undefined using imperative apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I have a variable, `this.myVariable` that is set to the results of a query that is called using imperative apex. When I try to print the value to the console log, I get `undefined` as the value.

**Question**

1. How come the variable is `undefined` after calling the imperative method?
2. how can i return the value so that it is not `undefined`?

**What I Tried**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import myMethod from '@salesforce/apex/MyApexController.myApexMethod'
export default class mycomponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
   myVariable;

   connectedCallback() {
       this.start();

       // it prints `undefined` in the console log
      console.log('myvariable: ' JSON.stringify(this.myVariable));
   }

   start() {
       myMethod()
         .then((results) => {
             this.myVariable = results;
         })
         .catch((error) => {
             /* process logic for error */
         });
   }
}
```

Comment: Note: api variables are intended to be read-only. If you attempt to modify them in any way, your code may break or behave unpredictability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using asynchronous processing to set the variable. Notice the `.then` and `.catch` indicating your use of promises. So effectively, your `console.log` fires before your `.then` success handler. If you want to debug it, you should put it in that handler instead. You also have an extra closing parenthesis after both `results` and `error`.

```
.then((results) => {
    this.myVariable = results;
    // log here
})
.catch((error) => {
    // error handling logic
})
```

Comment: Also, api properties are meant to be read-only, so violating that rule can negative side effects.

Comment: @AdrianLarson moving it into the handler worked. I did also update my code to not have extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: @sfdcfox good catch, that skipped my mind. I will update it.

Comment: @sfdcfox Why are we allowed to have `@api` enabled setters then? 

Comment: @AdrianLarson Because they're not properties in the same sense that "real" properties are.